# Как определить разрешение экрана?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Товарищи, как с помощью jQuery определить разрешение экрана и в зависимости от результата подгрузить нужный файл на PHP?

Comment: Разрешение экрана и размеры просматриваемой области браузера - это вещи разные. Так вам надо именно разрешение?

Comment: Было бы замечательно получить разрешение если такое возможно

Comment: Если не секрет, какая задача перед вами стоит? Для разработки сайтов под разные разрешения есть более удобные технологии. Да и отделить мобильную версию от десктопной, думаю, можно сразу, определив по клиенту. можно ведь? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно. Вот таким образом:

```
ScreenWidth = screen.width;     
ScreenHeight = screen.height;     
alert(ScreenWidth+'x'+ScreenHeight);
```

Comment: а как в зависимости от получего результата подгрузить фаил ??

Comment: Вогнали в ступор ))) Уж не знаю с чего начать, но может быть вы слышали что-нибудь про условные операторы? Ну, там таки штучки, как  **if ... else ...**

Comment: Конечно слышали но с JS не дружу вообще даже не представляю как все что нужно завязать друг с другом. А сделать нужно

Comment: Может тогда хоть проясните, какого плана файл собираетесь подгружать: css, php, js, etc.?

Comment: Планируется PHP но хотелось бы узнать как и CSS подгрузить

Comment: Пример для CSS:

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 980px)" />

Тут и JS кода не нужно.

Comment: А для PHP ??

Comment: Разные способы можно применить, но все зависит от определенных условий и задач. Вот один из них - [.load()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_HTML-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Answer (score 1):

высота видимой части экрана на клиенте (js)

```
var scrollHeight = Math.max(
    document.body.scrollHeight,
    document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
    document.body.offsetHeight,
    document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
    document.body.clientHeight,
    document.documentElement.clientHeight
);
```

[js width height](http://itforweb.com/content/e410/)